# make a webpage responsive through HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

With changing the size of the screen the content of the heading and the footer do not move with the screen.

Firstly, I think there is something wrong with the css of the images which I could not fix them.

Secondly, the header does not follow the screen although I put the width for it and make the margin auto.

Thirdly, there is a same story for the footer and the content of that. I really appreciate if someone can help me to fix these bugs.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#Container {
  width: 1100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#Header {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
}

#Logo {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 4px;
}

#HomeLogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 650px;
  top: 30px;
}

#MainMenu {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  top: 50px;
}

#MainMenu a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#MainMenu a:hover {
  background-color: #b404ae;
}

#ClickableButton {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#ClickableButton:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#DropdownContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 88px;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
}

#DropdownContent a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

#DropdownContent a:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#Dropbtn:hover #DropdownContent {
  display: block;
}

#Sector {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #eff8fb;
}

#Footer {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

pre {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#underline>pre:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css" media="screen and (min-width:0)" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>First website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Container">
    <div id="Header">
      <div id="Logo">
        <a href="http://www.manchester.ac.uk/">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/UniOfManchesterLogo.svg" width="150" height="80" alt="University logo">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="HomeLogo">
        <a href="main.html">
          <figure>
            <img src="http://www.diywebsitetools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/homeicon.jpg" class="img-rounded" width="120" height="70" alt="going back to the main page">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="MainMenu">
        <a href=M.html> M&S </a>
        <a href="#Health & saftely issues when working with computers"> Health&Saftely </a>
        <span id="Dropbtn">
        <button id="ClickableButton">U&C</button>
          <div id="DropdownContent">
            <a href="#1">Statistics and backgroud information</a>
            <a href="#2">Research groups / research projects</a>
            <a href="#3">Courses</a>
          </div>
       </span>
        <a href="aboutUs.html"> About us </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Sector"></div>
    <div id="Footer">
      <pre>         Contact Us                                                                            Find Us                                                                        Copyright © 2017-2018 Group 4</pre>
      <div id="underline">
        <pre>         +44 (0) 161 306 60000                                                        The University of Manchester                                        Hossein Miraftabi
                                                                                                          Oxford Rd                                                                      Matthew Knowles
                                                                                                          Manchester                                                                    Catherine Dimitropoulaki
                                                                                                          M14 9PL                                                                        Sumera Zulfiqar
                                                                                                          UK</pre>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: First of all can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: @Traver He, more appropriately, provided the code here plus the snippet tool. A fiddle isn't needed nor should be made.

Comment: Agreed. My bad.

Comment: why dont you use bootstrap?

Comment: Giving downvotes on people's trials to help you is never a good idea unless you are fully aware of what they have typed.

Comment: @dehood not everything should be answered with bootstrap

Comment: @dehood Bootstrap? It’s a bit heavy-handed for a simple responsive layout. It’s very complex on the inside, doesn’t play with other solutions, and a developer will never learn anything if they instantly reach for some other package.

Comment: Can I recommend that, if you’re going for a responsive design, that you finish the job and look at using the correct HTML5 elements? Apart from simplifying some of your CSS, it also makes the role of the containers more obvious. Also, I see that you have used the HTML5 `figure` element. You could also look into using the `picture` element to make your image more responsive as well.

Comment: @Manngo it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your HTML and CSS and created new Layout for responsive.

Please check this. It will surely help you.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#Header {
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
}

#Logo {
    position: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;

}

#HomeLogo {
  position: inherit;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}

#MainMenu {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: -6px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

#MainMenu a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#MainMenu a:hover {
  background-color: #b404ae;
}

#ClickableButton {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#ClickableButton:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#DropdownContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 88px;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
}

#DropdownContent a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

#DropdownContent a:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#Dropbtn:hover #DropdownContent {
  display: block;
}

#Sector {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #eff8fb;
}

#Footer {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#Footer div{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#Footer div p, #Footer div h2{
font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

pre {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#underline>pre:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Header">
      <div id="Logo">
        <a href="http://www.manchester.ac.uk/">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/UniOfManchesterLogo.svg" width="150" height="80" alt="University logo">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="HomeLogo">
        <a href="main.html">
          <figure>
            <img src="http://www.diywebsitetools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/homeicon.jpg" class="img-rounded" width="120" height="70" alt="going back to the main page">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="MainMenu">
        <a href=M.html> M&S </a>
        <a href="#Health & saftely issues when working with computers"> Health&Saftely </a>
        <span id="Dropbtn">
        <button id="ClickableButton">U&C</button>
          <div id="DropdownContent">
            <a href="#1">Statistics and backgroud information</a>
            <a href="#2">Research groups / research projects</a>
            <a href="#3">Courses</a>
          </div>
       </span>
        <a href="aboutUs.html"> About us </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Sector"></div>
    <div id="Footer">
     <div class="footer-col1">
         <h2>Contact Us</h2>
         <p>+44 (0) 161 306 60000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col2">
         <h2>Find Us </h2>
            <p>The University of Manchester<br/>Oxford Rd  <br/> Manchester <br/>M14     9PL, UK </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col3">
        
            <p>Copyright © 2017-2018 Group 4</p>
            <p>Hossein Miraftabi</p>
            <p> Matthew Knowles</p>
            <p>Catherine Dimitropoulaki</p>
            <p>Sumera Zulfiqar</p>
        </div>
     

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The footer does not work for me. Moreover, there is "pre" and "underline" tag in your CSS file, but they are not exist in the HTML file

Comment: In footer the elements are below each other. They are not next to each one like your snipped code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use pixels instead use percentage for: font-size,border, width and height of the html and the body.Use vh for width and height of the div and other elements.

Answer (score -1):

Use max-width:

```
#Container {
   max-width: 1100px;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 20px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using fixed widths for your elements **will not** allow them to scale when the window resizes.

At first glance, you can change your container width from `width: 1100px` to `max-width: 1100px` , where `max-width` will give it a width of no more than 1100px and will re-scale on window resize.

Your second issue is that you are using `relative` or `absolute` positioning for some of your elements. In this particular case, you should stick to `margin` or `padding` offsets for your elements. Right now, your relatively positioned elements are offset from the center of their exact place and will not scale as expected on window resize. This is the main reason you think that your images's CSS is broken. Absolute positioning pulls out the elements from the document flow - e.g. removes them from their original spot.

Here is a quick sample using your html and css.

> Bottom line is, you just have to spend more time learning how CSS positioning works.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#Container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}

#Header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#Logo {
  margin: 4px 0 0 20px;
}

#MainMenu {
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
}

#MainMenu a {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#MainMenu a:hover {
  background-color: #b404ae;
}

#ClickableButton {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#ClickableButton:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#DropdownContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 88px;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
}

#DropdownContent a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

#DropdownContent a:hover {
  background: #b404ae;
}

#Dropbtn:hover #DropdownContent {
  display: block;
}

#Sector {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #eff8fb;
}

#Footer {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

pre {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvettica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#underline>pre:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css" media="screen and (min-width:0)" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>First website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Container">
    <div id="Header">
      <div id="Logo">
        <a href="http://www.manchester.ac.uk/">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/UniOfManchesterLogo.svg" width="150" height="80" alt="University logo">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="HomeLogo">
        <a href="main.html">
          <figure>
            <img src="http://www.diywebsitetools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/homeicon.jpg" class="img-rounded" width="120" height="70" alt="going back to the main page">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="MainMenu">
        <a href=M.html> M&S </a>
        <a href="#Health & saftely issues when working with computers"> Health&Saftely </a>
        <span id="Dropbtn">
        <button id="ClickableButton">U&C</button>
          <div id="DropdownContent">
            <a href="#1">Statistics and backgroud information</a>
            <a href="#2">Research groups / research projects</a>
            <a href="#3">Courses</a>
          </div>
       </span>
        <a href="aboutUs.html"> About us </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Sector"></div>
    <div id="Footer">
      <pre>         Contact Us                                                                            Find Us                                                                        Copyright © 2017-2018 Group 4</pre>
      <div id="underline">
        <pre>         +44 (0) 161 306 60000                                                        The University of Manchester                                        Hossein Miraftabi
                                                                                                          Oxford Rd                                                                      Matthew Knowles
                                                                                                          Manchester                                                                    Catherine Dimitropoulaki
                                                                                                          M14 9PL                                                                        Sumera Zulfiqar
                                                                                                          UK</pre>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```